# Linking a Discord bot with Django site / Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

has anyone managed to link their discord bot with a website they have created? I have a discord bot written in python and I want to link it with a Django site I have created to take certain data from the bot and upload it to my site...

I dont expect the code to be written for me I just was wondering if anyone has done this before and how I should approach this..

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably write some sort of curl/requests http request that will POST discord bot data to your django app and have the django app store it in a db

Comment: So I understand that I can use cURL to pull data from a website, but I am not sure you can use it to send data to a websites... I would somehow have to prove that I have admin privileges for the site within the bots code also.... not really sure how

Comment: You would write endpoints with authentication: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: I am 1000% sure you can use it to send data to a website. It acts like any other http request, you just need to provide the correct authentication credentials in the request